# HSQLDB trigger After Update unexpected token: FROM required: INTO

Tags: sql, triggers, hsqldb

I try to buid this trigger in HsqlDB, without SELECT statement it work fine but when i put a select statment i got this error unexpected token: FROM required: INTO

```
 CREATE TRIGGER PUBLIC.TRIGGERNAME AFTER UPDATE ON PUBLIC.CLIENTE_OFFERENTE 
 REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NUOVO 
     FOR EACH ROW 
           BEGIN ATOMIC 
               IF NUOVO.STATO='Venduto'
                              THEN
                              (SELECT IDIMMOBILE AS IDIMM FROM OFFERTA WHERE IDOFFERTA=NUOVO.IDOFFERTA); 
                            INSERT INTO PUBLIC.VENDITE(IDCLIENTE,IDIMMOBILE)VALUES(NUOVO.IDCLIENTE,IDIMM);END IF;END$
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal SELECT statements are not allowed here because they do nothing.

You need something like this:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC 
    DECLARE VAR_IDIMM INT;
    IF NUOVO.STATO='Venduto' THEN
        SELECT IDIMMOBILE INTO VAR_IDIMM FROM OFFERTA WHERE IDOFFERTA=NUOVO.IDOFFERTA; 
        INSERT INTO PUBLIC.VENDITE(IDCLIENTE,IDIMMOBILE)VALUES(NUOVO.IDCLIENTE,VAR_IDIMM);
    END IF;
END
```

Choose the correct type for VAR_IDIMM to be the same as the IDIMMOBILI column. Use the latest HSQLDB 2.2.9.

Comment: ok, now it work, i put my select statement before IF an i set it. thanks a lot